# Triggering a jQuery custom event in a separate div when user starts typing in a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a separate div (a custom 'continue' button) to appear when the user starts typing into a text input.
I am currently using this:

```
var submitButton = $('#submitButton');
submitButton.hide();
submitButton.on("showSubmitButton", function(event) {
    $( this ).show();
    $( this ).css('opacity', '0');
    $( this ).fadeTo(400, 0.6);
});
var textInput = $('#textInput');
textInput.click(function() {
    $( this ).find('input:text').val(''); // this clears the default 'type your name here' text 
});
textInput.keyDown(function() {
    submitButton.trigger("showSubmitButton");
});
```

When I had the "showSubmitButton" line inside the textInput.click function the submit button appeared on the click, but I want the button only to appear when the user has typed something into the input.
I have also used .keyPress(), but both key events trigger a 'has no method' error. I assume I must be using them incorrectly, but I don't know how.

Comment: TIP, line 4,5,6 why not chain it instead of typing $(this) 3 times?like show().css().fadeTo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorthand functions for event handlers aren't camel case, so it's `.keydown()`, `.keypress()`, etc. rather than `.keyDown()` or `.keyPress()`. That said, I'd use either the `input` or `keypress` events (depending on browser support), with a check to see if the value of the textbox isn't an empty string:

```
textInput.find('input:text').on('input', function(e) {
    if($.trim(this.value).length > 0) {
        submitButton.trigger('showSubmitButton');
    }
    else {
        // consider hiding the submit button?
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've just realised (just after I posted this question, or course!) that there's no camel-case in the keydown event. So it was the capital D that was throwing it out. It works now. Thanks for the answer too - I may give that alternative a go.

Comment: Thanks - your alternative works nicely. I changed the 'length > 0' to 'length < 2' so that it only triggers on the first input (it will also trigger when the user deletes down to 1 character-length, but I can live with that).

Answer (score 1):

It is not keyDown - it is keydown